# Duda con una practica

Tags: java, try-catch

tengo una duda con una practica. Ha de realizarse con grafos obligatoriamente pero no entiendo mucho de ellos. ¿Cómo podría hacer esto mismo sin usar el try-catch?

```
// Return a Hamiltonian path for the stored graph, or null if there is non.
// The list containts a series of vertices, with no repetitions (even if the path
// can be expanded to a cycle).
public PositionList <Vertex<V>> tour() { 
    PositionList<Vertex<V>> path = null;
    boolean found=false;
    Iterator<Vertex<V>> it = graph.vertices().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext() && found==false) {
        path = new NodePositionList<Vertex<V>>();;
        Vertex<V> startVert = it.next();
        try {
            if (graph.outDegree(startVert)!=0) {
                path.addLast(startVert);
                path = HamiltonianPath(path, this.getGraph(), startVert);
                if(path.size()==places.length) found=true;
            }
        }
        catch(java.lang.NullPointerException e) {}
    }
    if(!found) return null;
    return path;
}
```

Toda ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias

Comment: el try catch te permite controlar si peta la accion que quieres hacer y no pete el programa, como poder poder puede ser pero es posible que sea obligatorio ponerlo

Comment: en este caso no es obligatorio usarlo. Esta era una idea que se me ocurrio hacer, pero solo quiero saber como se podría hacer sin ese try-catch

Comment: Quita el try-catch, ejecútalo y comprueba donde falla. Añade un if para evitar el fallo y listo. En este caso la excepción podría saltar cuando `graph`, `path` o `places` es `null`, pero `graph` y `path` no pueden ser porque fallaría antes del `try`. Nos queda `places` o que realmente el fallo ocurra en la llamada a `HamiltonianPath`, que es un método y debería empezar con minúscula